Blazor Server - Microsoft Identity Web App and Web API
My Blazor Server offers anm API and a Web App. The API is used by desktop clients and the web app is like a admin tool to configure and setup things on the server.
Now I want to use my AzureAD to authenticate and authorize my Users.
Therefore I use @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")] for my razor pages and [Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")] attribute for my controllers.
My AzureAd configuration looks like this:
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "[mydomain.com]",
  "TenantId": "[myTenantId]",
  "ClientId": "[myClientId]",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
}

Authentication and Authorization with the web app OR the web API is working.
Web API Startup.cs:
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(GetConfiguration());
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor();

Web App Startup.cs:
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(GetConfiguration());
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

But I failed to config my Startup.cs to use both so far. It should work, here is a example.
Current attempt:
var configuration = GetConfiguration();
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration);
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(configuration);
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

Any ideas how so solve this?
Edit 1: For my current attempt the authentication for my clients via AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication is working but if I try to authenticate in my web app the AzureAd login kind of succeeds, but after the redirect to my app there is no user logged in.
Edit 2: Related question: Using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi and AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp in the same ASP.NET Core 7 application

In your Blazor app, you don't use the MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication middleware, just the MicrosoftIdentityWebApp middleware. Inside AD, all three apps must be registered. Then add the API scope to your Blazor registered app inside AD and reference that inside your MicrosoftIdentityWebApp middleware like so: options.Scope.Add("https://myadb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/GUID/MyScopeName")

But for my current attempt as soon as I remove one of the middlewares the other one works perfectly fine for their purpose. So I asume on the Azure AD side everything is registered and setup correctly. Am I wrong?

@GHDevOps Like adding "Scopes": [ "api://[MyClientId]/access_as_user" ] to the AzureAd config section? I only have registered one app inside AzureAD and did all the configs there, including exposing an API with this scope (e.g. access_as_user).

You need all three in Azure. For example, your web app will need to expose API endpoints (ie reading, writing, etc...) for your Blazor app to access. Register the web app, and expose the api endpoints. Then register your Blazor app and set up API permissions to access the web app. Look at AD app registrations, API Permissions and how to expose an API for AD B2C tenant.

@GHDevOps Can you give me a little bit more details here. You talking about three app, so far I have one app registered in azure. On the other side I have a Blazor Server and a desktop client (both .Net6.0). You can argue they both need their own Azure app registration, but whats the third one?

I think I fixed it. Thanks to LeeAdamas stackoverflow question and answer.
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);

services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration);

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
            JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

And changed the attributes of my controllers like this:
[Authorize(Roles = "[MyRoleDefinedInAzureAd]", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
   ...
}

AzureAd config section is unchanged and I only have one Azure app registration and Azure enterprise application to get it running.
